# Problem with dynamic SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stored procedure

```
create or replace  procedure GETFILE(TableName in VARCHAR2)
is
No_Rows Number :=0;
state varchar2(100);
begin
state :=' select    count(*)  into   :p_id     from   ' || inTableName;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE state using out NO_ROWS;

end;
end;
```

Stored procedure is getting created successfully.
But when i am running it using:

```
declare
begin
GETFILE('TABLE_NAME');
end;
```

It showing "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist"
error.
Any idea?

Comment: Beware of SQL injection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for your requirement ( you may want to remove the put_line )...:

```
create or replace  procedure GETFILE(inTableName in VARCHAR2)
is
No_Rows Number :=0;
state varchar2(100);
begin
 state :=' select    count(*)   from   ' || inTableName;
dbms_output.put_line(state);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE state into NO_ROWS;
dbms_output.put_line(no_rows);
end;
/

declare
begin
getfile('dual');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any coding error here 
so, I think you have to ensure that you are creating and executing your procedure 
at the same data base or at the same schema